# Software Center cannot be reinstalled

Tags: apt, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2.

I cannot find Ubuntu Software (or Software center) in my dash.
I have tried to install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install software-center*
```

After all the processes have run I get the following message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

I think the problem might be related to my earlier attempt to install the MATE desktop environment. Since it failed I purged the installed packages. I assume that when I purged MATE packages I also deleted the software center and something that is needed its re-installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `software-center` [does not exist in 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=software-center), use `gnome-software` instead.

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: Thank you, it has solved my problem!