# Install via Ubuntu Software vs. apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation

It seems to be that when I install an application via command line (with `sudo apt-get someapp`), that the application does not appear in the Ubuntu Software list. Is it possible to get such applications to appear there?

---

Running the command in the comments, it updates and I see this:

```
...  
All packages are up to date.  
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.   
GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13  
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.   
GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13  
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13  
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

---

```
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Try sudo apt update && sudo apt —reinstall software-center

Comment: What are the character or characters immediately preceding "reinstall"?

Comment: Just 2 dashes  "-"

Comment: `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt --reinstall software-center` causes message "E: Command line option --reinstall is not understood in combination with the other options"

Comment: Sorry it must be sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall software-center

Comment: ok, works. See edit to original question. I don't think it's doing anything.

Comment: You should to fix all those NO_PUBKEY errors before you do anything else. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065. After fixing, we could help you better if you provide an example.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I've fixed that problem now. See new addition to question for latest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software Center cannot be reinstalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148592/software-center-cannot-be-reinstalled)

Comment: When I do `gnome-software` instead of `software-center`, it says "gnome-software is already the newest version (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14)."

Comment: I do not quite understand why you believe that reinstalling Ubuntu Software (gnome-software) will fix the problem. It might, it might not. Can you provide an example of an application that is available using apt but NOT in Ubuntu Software? That would help us to help you.

Comment: "...why you believe that reinstalling Ubuntu Software (gnome-software) will fix the problem."  I'm just following instructions.  Applications: GIMP, QGIS

Comment: Hmmm. Both GIMP and QGIS are showing properly in Ubuntu Software on my 18.04 test system and my 19.10 test system. Have they always been missing from yours? Or is this new? Did the reinstall of gnome-software have any effect? Are you browsing through the categories? Or using the Search feature? Or both? Exactly which release/flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: I just installed QGIS today. GIMP I've had for a long time. Reinstall had no effect. Both browsing and search. When I click on Unbuntu Software and do a search for GIMP, it finds it and shows that it is not installed. I've just noticed if I click on Show Applications (icon is a grid of 3x3 white dots) then I do see the applications. Just not in Ubuntu Software (icon is an orange folder with A on it).  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: No. As I said in a previous comment, I have now fixed this.